# Flask Internal Server Error but no error log

Tags: flask

I am new to flask and tried to run this simple code from GeeksForGeeks

form.html

```
<form action="{{ url_for("gfg")}}" method="post">
<label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" placeholder="firstname">
<label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" placeholder="lastname">
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

flask_text.py

```
# importing Flask and other modules
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

# Flask constructor
app = Flask(__name__)

# A decorator used to tell the application
# which URL is associated function
@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def gfg():
    if request.method == "POST":
    # getting input with name = fname in HTML form
    first_name = request.form.get("fname")
    # getting input with name = lname in HTML form
    last_name = request.form.get("lname")
    return "Your name is "+first_name + last_name
    return render_template("form.html")

if __name__=='__main__':
app.run()
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/retrieving-html-from-data-using-flask/

You can find the code in the above link
I added app.debug = True but got no error log

I have my html file in /templates folder

Comment: I don't know how you are running Flask but this code seems to be syntactically wrong: the ifs are not properly indented - unless it was pasted wrong. Running it from the command line should show errors + debug messages eg: python3 flask_text.py

Answer (score 0):

First,  The indentation of your code is wrong. Try this:

```
# importing Flask and other modules
from flask import Flask, request, render_template 
  
# Flask constructor
app = Flask(__name__)   
  
# A decorator used to tell the application
# which URL is associated function
@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def gfg():
    if request.method == "POST":
       # getting input with name = fname in HTML form
       first_name = request.form.get("fname")
       # getting input with name = lname in HTML form 
       last_name = request.form.get("lname") 
       return "Your name is "+first_name + last_name
    return render_template("form.html")
  
if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run()
```

Second, is your virtual environment running? (Can you see '(env)' at the start of your command line?)
If not, you need to first execute:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

and then pip3 install flask

If it still does not work, give me some more context.

Comment: I am not running it on a virtual environment put the applications seems to work now after a system reboot